# login user data does not persist once I refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

Hi I am using express for backend authentication and these are my sign in functions/controllers on the front end.

```
export const signInUser = async credentials => {
    console.log('this is for the signInUser', credentials)
  try {
    const resp = await api.post('/sign-in', credentials)
    localStorage.setItem('token', resp.data.token)
    return resp.data
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}

    onSignIn = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        const { history, setUser } = this.props
        signInUser(this.state)
            .then(res => setUser(res.user))
            .then(() => history.push('/Home'))
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
                this.setState({
                    loginUsername: '',
                    loginPassword: '',
                })
            })
    }

setUser = user => this.setState({ user })
```

and this is my sign in controller on the backend

```
const signIn = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('hello' ,req.body);
    const { loginUsername, username, loginPassword } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        username: loginUsername
      }
    });
    console.log('this is the user', user)
    if (await bcrypt.compare(loginPassword, user.dataValues.password_digest)) {
      const payload = {
        id: user.id,
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
      };
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, TOKEN_KEY);
      return res.status(201).json({ user, token });
    } else {
      res.status(401).send("Username or Password is invalid- try again.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

The issue is the state of the user doesn't persist on refresh but I still have the json webtoken in my local storage and this is an issue when I make post requests and even signing up since I am redirecting to the home page and losing the user state. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you refresh, localStorage won't get deleted so you will have access to the token you stored. But any other info should be sent from backend to the frontend. Can backend successfully send the user data?

Comment: Yes the authentication and sending the user data from back to front works fine.

Answer (score 1):

From your tags, I noticed that you are using `React`, so the solution is simple!

you can have an `GlobalAuthManager` context for your application that would wrap all the components at the most higher level! after `<React.strictMode>` like below:

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <GlobalAuthManager.Provider value={{authData}}>
    <App />
  </GlobalAuthManager.Provider>
</React.StrictMode>
```

As you might guess, this would be a context! that would provide you your user data to all your components!

### The Pattern:

**1. Store token:**

when your user logins to your app, you would receive a token ( in your response or in response header ), you need to store the token value in localstorage, or more better in cookie storage (there are a lot of articles about it why), one is [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/#:%7E:text=A%20JWT%20needs%20to%20be,storage%20(or%20session%20storage).).

**2. have a `/getUserData` endpoint in backend:**

you need to have a `/getUserData` endpoint in backend to retrive your user data based on token

**3. call `/getUserData` in app mount:**

before every thing in your app, you need to call this endpoint if you find token in localstorage or cookie storage. so if you run this in your `componnetDidMount` or `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])`, that would work!

**4. store your user data and state in context:**

after you've called the `/getUserData` and if you had a valid token(i mean not expired token or not interrupted and edited token) , you will get you user data and what you need to do is that you need to store this in your `GlobalAuthManager`  and provide that in to your Global App component!

after that you have your user data available to you that you can decide to show login or sign up button in your Navbar or disable/enable comment section for example based on your user data!

Wrap up:
So the key is that you have to have a `GlobalAuthManager` for only one purpose, that before every thing it runs in the top level in your app and gets you your user data based on provided token from localstorage or cookie storage!

after that you can manage your app state based on that your user is logged in or not!